# Unable to transfer Data from models to html using templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

View.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Albums
from django.template import loader

def index(request):
    all_albums = Albums.objects.all()

    template = loader.get_template('Ganaana/index.html')
    context = {
        'all_albums':all_albums,
        }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))

def define(request,Albums_id):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Your Id is "+str(Albums_id)+"</h1>");
```

index.html

```
<html>
  <ul>  
    <% for albums in all_albums %>  
       <li><a href="/music/{{albums.id}}/">{{albums.artist}}</a></li>  
    <% endfor %>  
  </ul>  
</html>
```

output of code:

```
  <% for albums in all_albums %>
     albums.artist
  <% endfor %>
```

I dont know what the error i used templates folder and put data in it i dont understand what the problem i import class correctly.. i dont understand?

Comment: We don't understand either, because you haven't told us at all what problem you are encountering with this code.

Comment: Plus, Python code does not use semicolons at the end of lines, and indentation is significant.

Comment: @DanielRoseman sir my output is not proper on the webpage i have adjusted the code Please review it. Maybe Now you can understand my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, "Ganaana/index.html", {"all_albums": Albums.objects.all()})
```